# Can we list notifications we receive for incoming message inside ListView?

Tags: android, listview, notifications

I'm developing an app in which the app has to show the receiving messages starts with `#`. Now i have to show notification for them and i also want to update the notifications in a `ListView` inside an `Activity`. Currently i get the messages from inbox using `ContentResolver`. Because of that once processed messages still shows up in activity. I don't want to show that. I want notifications i receive for the messages starts with `#` listed in `ListView` inside an activity.
My Code is 
My Activity

```
    public class ActivationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    private static ActivationActivity inst;
    ArrayList<String> smsMessagesList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView smsListView;
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    Context context;

    public static ActivationActivity instance() {
        return inst;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        inst = this;
    }

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_activation);
        smsListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,smsMessagesList);
        smsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        refreshSmsInbox();
        smsListView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    }


    public void refreshSmsInbox(){
        ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
        final Cursor smsInboxCursor=contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),null,null,null,null);
        int indexBody=smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body");
        int indexAddress=smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("address");
        if (indexBody<0||!smsInboxCursor.moveToFirst()) return;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        do {
            if (smsInboxCursor.getString(smsInboxCursor.getColumnIndex("body")).startsWith("#")) {
                String str =  smsInboxCursor.getString(indexAddress)+ smsInboxCursor.getString(indexBody)+"\n";
                arrayAdapter.add(str);
            }else {
            }
        } while (smsInboxCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    public void updateList(final String smsMessage) {
            arrayAdapter.insert(smsMessage, 0);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                try{
                    String[] smsMessages=smsMessagesList.get(position).split("#");
                    String address=smsMessages[0];
                    String dCode=smsMessages[1];
                    String user=smsMessages[2];
                    String addrs1=smsMessages[3];
                    String pin=smsMessages[4];
                    String addrs=addrs1+","+pin;
                    String sNo=smsMessages[5];

                    databaseHelper=new DatabaseHelper(this);
                    SQLiteDatabase db=databaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();

                    SmsManager smsManager=SmsManager.getDefault();

                    Cursor cursor= db.rawQuery("select uSerialNo,dealerCode from unittable", null);
                   cursor.moveToFirst();
                    String srNo=cursor.getString(0);
                    String drCode=cursor.getString(1);
                    if (srNo.equals(sNo) || drCode.equals(dCode)){
                        ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();
                        cv.put("userName",user);
                        cv.put("mobileNo", address);
                        cv.put("address", addrs);
                        db.update("unittable", cv, "uSerialNo='" + srNo + "'", null);
                        db.update("unittable", cv, "uSerialNo='" + srNo + "'", null);
                        db.update("unittable", cv, "uSerialNo+'" + srNo + "'", null);
                        Toast.makeText(ActivationActivity.this,"Updation Success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(address,null,"YES. ACTIVATE. Default Password is 1234",null,null);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ActivationActivity.this,"Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        smsManager.sendTextMessage(address,null,"NO. Details or Incorrect. Check the details or Call the Customer Care",null,null);
                    }

                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
    }
}
```

My BroadcastReceiver is

```
public class SmsBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String smsBundle="pdus";

public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
    Bundle intentExtras=intent.getExtras();
    if (intentExtras!=null){
        Object[] sms=(Object[])intentExtras.get(smsBundle);
        String SmsManager="";
            for (int i = 0; i < sms.length; i++) {
                SmsMessage smsMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) sms[i]);
                    String smsBody = smsMessage.getMessageBody().toString();
                    String smsAddress = smsMessage.getOriginatingAddress();
                    SmsManager += "SMS From: " + smsAddress + "\n";
                    SmsManager += smsBody + "\n";
                }
            Toast.makeText(context, SmsManager, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

            ActivationActivity inst = ActivationActivity.instance();
            inst.updateList(SmsManager);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need to save your own database, or can you just query the SMS Provider each time your Activity resumes?